# Basic Polymorphism Confusion in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm reading Python 3 Object-Oriented Programming and am a bit confused by one of the examples.  It's ch. 3, p. 78:

```
class AudioFile:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        if not filename.endswith(self.ext):
            raise Exception("Invalid file format")
        self.filename = filename

class MP3File(AudioFile):
    ext = "mp3"
    def play(self):
        print("playing {} as mp3".format(self.filename))
```

So `MP3File` inherits from `AudioFile`.  How is `AudioFile`, the superclass, able to access `self.ext`?  For instance, Java has abstract classes, so there's no guarantee that AudioFile can necessarily be instantiated / has an `ext` field.  More to the point, I thought that subclasses inherit all info from superclasses but that there was no flow of information in the other direction.

Seems I'm wrong...

Any clarification would be great,

bclayman

Comment: It cannot access `self.ext` it will throw an error `AttributeError: 'AudioFile' object has no attribute 'ext'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that there is no guarantee that an AudioFile will have an `ext` attribute.  If you were to instantiate AudioFile directly, or write a subclass that didn't define `ext` and instantiate that, then trying to access `self.ext` would indeed fail.

So you could consider AudioFile to be an abstract class, in that it relies on its subclasses filling in details in order for AudioFile itself to work correctly.  But in Python this kind of abstractness is not encoded by the language; you would just document that people have to write subclasses of AudioFile that define `ext`, and if they don't then they may encounter errors.  (Some other kinds of abstractness can be handled by the [`abc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) module, although in practice they are often handled via documentation convention as well.)

As for how AudioFile can access the attribute given that it exists. . . well, it accesses it on the instance, not the class.  Once you instantiate `MP3File` with something like `obj = MP3File()`, you have an instance object `obj`.  Doing `obj.ext` on that object will return its `ext` attribute, or, if the instance has no attribute of its own, it will look for such an attribute on its class (and then on its superclasses all the way up).  This attribute lookup happens dynamically every time you try to access an attribute; you don't and can't "predeclare" where the attribute will be found (on the instance, the class, or some superclass way up the hierarchy).  So when an `AudioFile` that is also an `MP3File` does `self.ext`, it finds the attribute on `MP3File`, because `self` is an instance of `MP3File`.

If the book did not explain any of this by this point, then that example may not be the best one.  It works, but how it works is not obvious to users of other languages with different OO semantics.  Also, even if you do know Python, in a real-world situation it would be critical to have the documentation telling you how to use `AudioFile` (i.e., saying "you must subclass this and your subclass must define `ext`).

Comment: I suppose I thought that MP3File would inherit all the functions and fields from AudioFile but that this happens *before* instantiation.  Sounds like you're saying, "nah, an MP3File gets instantiated and has a field called `ext` and it so happens that MP3File inherits a function which makes use of this field.  Yes?  Sorry to pester but I'd like to understand what's really happening vs. ascribing it to "Python magic"

Comment: @bclayman: Basically yes.  In general much less happens before instantation in Python than in less dynamic languages.  In Python, almost nothing happens before instantiation.  In particular, the `__init__` method is run for each instance when it is instantiated.  The access to `self.ext` happens in `__init__`, so by the time that is run, the object has been instantiated.  Things that are inherited are not statically "copied" into the subclass when you define it; the inheritance just specifies a lookup path that is actually searched "on the fly" every single time you try to access an attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally the `AudioFile` should be an [abc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta) since it does have the field (self.ext) defined. If you try and instantiate `AudioFile` you should get an attribute error.

I think you're right .. The example just didn't want to go into abc just yet.